# Moment.JS: Why `===` or `==` or indexOf with the same date (a clone of the same moment) returns false (or -1)?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Why does this snippet log `false`, then `false`, then `-1`?  moment `y` is a clone of moment `x` after all!

(My goal is to locate a date (a moment) in an array using a clone of that date (moment). How can I reach my goal?)

```js
var x = moment();
var y = moment(x);

var a = moment();
var b = moment();
var c = moment();

console.log(x === y);
console.log(x == y);

var moments = [a, x, b, c];

console.log(moments.indexOf(y));


console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha256-TbOIe++NbC9P3KTtUMJ5wcROlBdnRqrPleLdpPg3xxE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Probably because those are objects you're comparing, so they will never evaluate as being the same. Try to get the timestamps and compare those.

Comment: @B.Fleming So, it would be impossible to use indexOf then? right? Am I obligated to use a for loop then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` and `y` are both object references, so checking whether they are equal is checking whether they are both the same object in memory, not whether the values inside those objects are the same. Moment.js provides some functions for comparing. For your case, `.isSame` should suffice:

```js
var x = moment();
var y = moment(x);


console.log(x.isSame(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

To check if an element in the array matches the time, you could use findIndex:

```js
var x = moment();
var y = moment(x);
var a = moment('2010-10-20');
var b = moment('2010-10-21');
var c = moment('2010-10-22');

var moments = [a, x, b, c];

const index = moments.findIndex(moment => moment.isSame(y));
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Mike by the way, here's some documentation on other comparisons you can do with moments: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/